# Fast measure of "clusteredness" of points?

Tags: clustering, density-function, nonparametric-density

I have a cloud of points in a bounded volume in 2D (lets say 2d for now, though it'd be nice to generalize to any dimension):

$<p_n \in \mathbb [0, 1]^2: n \in [1..N]>$

I'm looking for some efficient measure of the "clusteredness" of these points - ie how "clumped together" they are.

Characteristics that I would like this measure to have:

- Speed.  Ideally `O(N)` time to compute
- Boundedness - ideally it would be some number between 0 (uniformly distributed) and 1 (all concentrated at one location).
- Determinism/stability - Ideally, this measure would be reliable, and not change much if a different set of points are drawn from the same distribution.  (This might rule out something that uses e.g. k-means which depends on random initial values).
- Non-parametric or at least minimally parametric.  This would likely rule out any algorithm that makes prior assumptions on the number of possible clusters.
- Onlineness - Ideally, the measure could be computed online/incrementally - ie it could be updated in `O(1)` time when a new point comes in.

I've made a picture of what I imagine this measure being, on a set of hand-made pointclouds.

Does anyone know of some measure that roughly fits the bill?

[image]

Comment: Great question, I'm struggling even just to meet the nonparametric requirement. Do you have any such techniques in mind?

Comment: Well - they're not requirements, just desires.  The thing I was currently thinking of was just to break the space up into a grid, do a histogram, smooth the histogram (so parametric) to estimate density, and find mean density.  But it feels a little wrong to have to quantize, and even then, "mean density" is not quite the same as "clusteredness".  You could imagine two pointclouds with equal mean densities but very different "clusternesses".

Comment: That makes sense, but is going to be hard in high dimension; no grids that you can compute there :) First thing that jumped to my mind is related to cdf of distances (we expect jumps if there are clusters)

Comment: That's an interesting idea.  I suppose we could just take K randomly paired  distances per point to make it `O(NK)` - violating the determinism requirement but maybe not so much the stability.

Comment: Well, `O(NK log(NK))` since we'd have to sort the distances.

Comment: Yes, I think convergence theory of cdfs will actually allow us to get results O(k f(\epsilon)) in the sense that seeing at least $M$ many pairs gives us a $\epsilon$-good estimate of the cdf, but will be NlogN til then (not sure what f is). The thing I'm having trouble nailing down is what exactly do we do to the cdf :) Maybe the variance of its slope? PS: what would the ideal clustering metric assign to dataset consistence of concentric circles of increasing radius?

Comment: Hmm not sure but I'm thinking something pretty near zero - as I'm thinking of a "cluster" as being a set of points nearby in euclidian space - not the "DBSCAN-notion" of cluster where it's about connectivity - so even a single circular ring would have a low score.  I was think of the score as roughly aligning with "1/nClusters" - (as seen in the first 3 plots on top-row above) - with a smooth downward decay as clusters become less distinct.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138718/discussion-between-john-madden-and-peter).

Comment: One of often used and easy to do visual approach is the block-diagonalization. One of many algorithms do it is VAT (or better iVAT). Search internet "Clustering tendency, VAT iVAT"

Comment: Consider also just detecting polymodality in multivariate data.